# SQL update one column from another column in another table through another table

Tags: mysql, sql

How can i update customer city when i can not take city_name from relation countries.

```
UPDATE customers set customers.city = **countries.cities.city_name**
```

Comment: Do you have different databases here? `countries.cities.city_name` suggests a db called `countries`

Comment: Keep the city _name_ in the cities table. Don't copy data from table to table. it will only lead to data inconsistency.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that :

```
UPDATE customers set city = (select city_name from countries.cities where ...)
```

But then that's not how SQL is supposed to be done. Your cities should have an id, and you'd put that id into customers.city.

So that if the city_name changes sometimes, it gets changed in every customer records.